# Common folder/file structure in Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I have just created a flask application and so far I have a router for my "Hello world!" template.

I would like to add a little (a lot) more functionality, but I wonder how I should structure the app directory.

What's the most common way of structuring a Flask app?
For instance, should I create a `routes.py` for all my routes?
Where does the SQLAlchemy stuff go?
Should models be in `models.py`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should check out the Larger Applications page in the Patterns section of the Flask docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/. It seems to be the model that most people follow when their application calls for a package instead of a module.

I believe `views.py` is what you are calling `routes.py`. After that, models would go in `models.py`, forms would go in `forms.py`, etc.

Comment: I don't get that, why do we have just one file for all the models? What about the 'one class per file' practice? What if some models are quite big? Should we move some of the logic into other modules? And still, if I wanted my models to be in separate files, should I just create a module 'models'? Thanks!

Comment: @lime, how to structure project when there are more models?, i can you help me please.

Comment: @lime I'm not a fan of "one class per file." I find longer, repetitive import paths to be cumbersome. You also end up with a lot of extra imports to accommodate everything being separate, unless you import everything into an `__init__.py`, which can be hard to maintain. That said, you're free to structure your project however you'd like. I was merely offering a convention many people follow.

Comment: @dirn yeah, I guess there is no common structure. Different frameworks suggest various structures. Even Django say in the docs that the default structure is just a suggestion.

Comment: I think one class per file is great when the project grows, but if you only have 2-3 why bother. You can always split them when you need to. My guideline is when it fits my 19" screen its fine soon asI need to scroll, I split ...

Comment: Is it good practice to make your app installable? It will cause truble when you want to move your app to docker container.

Answer (score 48):

An example of a FlaskApp directory:

```
    /yourapp  
        /run.py  
        /config.py  
        /app  
            /__init__.py
            /views.py  
            /models.py  
            /static/  
                /main.css
            /templates/  
                /base.html  
        /requirements.txt  
        /yourappenv
```

`run.py` - contains the actual python code that will import the app and start the development server.
`config.py` - stores configurations for your app.
`__init__.py` - initializes your application creating a Flask app instance.
`views.py` - this is where `routes` are defined.
`models.py` - this is where you define models for your application.
`static` - contains static files i.e. CSS, Javascript, images
`templates` - this is where you store your `html` templates i.e. `index.html`, `layout.html`
`requirements.txt` - this is where you store your package dependancies, you can use `pip`
`yourappenv` - your virtual environment for development

Comment: For `requirement.txt` and `venv`.

Comment: dumb question, but are the 2nd and 3rd "/yourapp" supposed to be named the same? I'm a little confused on why there's 3 levels named "/yourapp"

Comment: @SourceMatters The first `/yourapp` wasn't really necessary, third one is `/app`.

Comment: thanks! that helps. i'm having trouble getting mine to run with blueprints (for use of a url_prefix). i'm not sure how to structure the code properly. works fine when running in debug in vscode, but running as gunicorn, it doesn't run.

Comment: Try [here](https://lepture.com/en/2018/structure-of-a-flask-project) and the official documentation.

Comment: for quick testing: `mkdir -p yourapp/{run.py,config.py,requirements.txt} && \
    mkdir -p yourapp/app/{__init__.py,views.py,models.py} && \
    mkdir -p yourapp/app/static/{main.css,} && \
    mkdir -p yourapp/app/templates/{base.html,}`

Answer (score 30):

I would say if you split the application use divisional rather than functional structure. 
I advocate this because you are more likely to work on 1 of these divisional components at any one time.

This type of structure lends itself well on marketplace or SaaS apps where different user groups use a different type of views. API only flask app I might use functional splitting.

Here are examples from Flask Blueprints. Blueprints are essentially documented advice how to split Flask application for more manageable pieces. More on this at : http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html

Here is an example of divisional splitting. See how each feature is grouped together.

```
yourapp/
    __init__.py
    admin/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        static/
        templates/
    home/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        static/
        templates/
    control_panel/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        static/
        templates/
    models.py
```

Here is the functional example >

```
yourapp/
    __init__.py
    static/
    templates/
        home/
        control_panel/
        admin/
    views/
        __init__.py
        home.py
        control_panel.py
        admin.py
    models.py
```

Comment: Neatly explained. Thank You!

Comment: thats great, any working demo on same structure?

Answer (score 12):

I think flask is micro framework and now you must decide how create files and folders.

i use this way :

- flask folders and files structure -> https://gist.github.com/4545740

this is near Django structure

i suggest you see some project to give you what you want

- danjac / newsmeme — Bitbucket -> https://bitbucket.org/danjac/newsmeme/overview
- sean-/flask-skeleton · GitHub -> https://github.com/sean-/flask-skeleton

Answer (score 11):

Anyone looking for a simple beginner-friendly structure for the flask project may find this helpful:

```
   |__movies 
     |__run.py 
     |__app     
        ├── templates
        │   └── index.html
        │   └── signup.html
        └── __init__.py
        └── routes.py
```

Here '*movies*' is the name given for the main application. It contains '*run.py*' and a folder called '*app*'.
'*app*' folder contains all necessary flask files such as '*templates*' folder, '*__init __.py*', and '*routes.py*'.

Contents of:

**run.py**:

```
from app import app
```

**__init.py__**:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes


app.run(debug=True)
```

**routes.py**:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: There is a circular dependency. This is nice but it is a hack

Comment: @JeanAlesi Can you explain further? Which dependency is circular, and what changes would be necessary to remove it?

Comment: @krubo __init__ <--- routes <--- __init__

Comment: so how do you avoid the circular dependency? what mods to this layout and file structure would be needed?

Comment: indeed getting a circular error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\..\app\__init__.py)`

Answer (score 9):

Beauty of flask lies in its flexibility. You can build django like project-structure easily. Django popularized abstraction of features in apps and making them reusable but it can be a overkill for many projects.

But with flask you can go either way. Write reusable apps or write simple apps. Check these cookiecutter skeletons -

1. [minimal skeleton](https://github.com/rohitchormale/cookiecutter-flask-minimal)

```
    myproject
    ├── config.py
    ├── instance
    │   └── config.py
    ├── myproject
    │   ├── commands.py
    │   ├── controllers.py
    │   ├── extensions.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── routes.py
    │   └── ui
    │       ├── static
    │       │   ├── css
    │       │   │   └── styles.css
    │       │   └── js
    │       │       └── custom.js
    │       └── templates
    │           └── index.html
    ├── README.md
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── wsgi.py
```

2. [django like skeleton](https://github.com/rohitchormale/cookiecutter-flask)

```
    myproject
    ├── config.py
    ├── development.py
    ├── instance
    │   └── config.py
    ├── myproject
    │   ├── auth
    │   │   ├── controllers.py
    │   │   ├── forms.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── models.py
    │   │   └── routes.py
    │   ├── helpers
    │   │   ├── controllers.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── models.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── ui
    │       └── templates
    │           ├── 404.html
    │           ├── 500.html
    │           └── base.html
    ├── README.md
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── tests
    │   ├── auth
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── test_controllers.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

This is an excellent [article](https://laymanclass.com/how-to-structure-flask-application-for-larger-projects/) on this.

Comment: Do you have a github example of this in practice? I'm still trying to figure what to put into `__init__.py` vs `wsgi.py`, for example.

Comment: @krubo content is already added in cookiecutter-minimal-skeleton (1st example link) . just create project using it. You will get everything ready.  check README for more info.

Answer (score 5):

You could get inspired by the cookiecutter templates here to jumpstart your app development

- https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone
- https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask

Answer (score 3):

Here is the basic file structure for flask I use regularly.

```
yourapp/
static/
    js
    css
    img

templates/
    home.html
    index.html

app.py
```

static folder contains all the static files of the website.
The templates folder contains all the HTML pages.
and app.py contains your python views.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to nest the source code folder under `src/`.

```
my_flask_app (project folder)
├── app.py
├── setup.py
├── src/
│   ├── my_flask_app/ (source code folder)
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   ├── errors.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   │   ├── static/
│   │   └── templates/
│   └── my_flask_app.egg-info/
|
└── tests/ (test folder)
```

Because of this, I added `package_dir={'': 'src'}` in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0):

good idea is to goole for sceletons/template projects on github

for example you can look at this

- https://github.com/xen/flask-project-template
- https://github.com/upperlinecode/flaskproject
- https://github.com/alisezer/flask-template

Answer (score 0):

In flask we can maintain the mvc structure like as separate all thinks
for example
1 Templets folder contains all html files
2 Static folder contains all css and boostrap related files
3 User defined db folder for db connection and crud operations
4 User defined Model folder for accessing/ binding the data from Templets/front- end to db/back-end connectivity
and after the main activity file
for reference flask file structure link as follow
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/layout/

Answer (score -1):

For larger projects here's what my directory structure looks like

```
app_name(root folder)
│  .env
│  .gitignore
│  .gitattributes
│  README.MD
│  pyproject.toml
│
└── app(source code)
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   __main__.py
│   │   db.py
│   │   auth.py
│   │   forms.py
│   │   utils.py
│   │   config.py
│   │
│   └─── routes
│          __init__.py
│          views.py
│          api.py
│          auth.py
│
└─ resources
│   |─── static
│   │       css
│   │       js        
│   │       images
│   │
│   └─── templates
│           base
|           components
│
└─ tests
└─ venv
└─ docs
```