# how to give structure to python flask application

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoalchemy

I am new to python flask

Experimenting some end points with MongoDB as shown below in a single file

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.ext.mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['MONGOALCHEMY_DATABASE'] = 'library'
db = MongoAlchemy(app)


class Author(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()


class Book(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField()
    author = db.DocumentField(Author)
    year = db.IntField();


@app.route('/author/new')
def new_author():
    """Creates a new author by a giving name (via GET parameter)
    e.g.: GET /author/new?name=Francisco creates a author named Francisco
    """
    author = Author(name=request.args.get('name', ''))
    author.save()
    return 'Saved :)'






@app.route('/authors/')
def list_authors():
    """List all authors.

    e.g.: GET /authors"""
    authors = Author.query.all()
    content = '<p>Authors:</p>'
    for author in authors:
        content += '<p>%s</p>' % author.name
    return content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Above code which contains two end points to post and get the data which is working fine

Know  looking for a way to separate the code into different file like

the database connection related code should be in different file

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.ext.mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['MONGOALCHEMY_DATABASE'] = 'library'
db = MongoAlchemy(app)
```

I should be able to get the DB reference in different files  where the schema is define and use it

```
class Author(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()


class Book(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField()
    author = db.DocumentField(Author)
    year = db.IntField();
```

and routes will be different file

```
@app.route('/author/new')
def new_author():
    """Creates a new author by a giving name (via GET parameter)
    e.g.: GET /author/new?name=Francisco creates a author named Francisco
    """
    author = Author(name=request.args.get('name', ''))
    author.save()
    return 'Saved :)'






@app.route('/authors/')
def list_authors():
    """List all authors.

    e.g.: GET /authors"""
    authors = Author.query.all()
    content = '<p>Authors:</p>'
    for author in authors:
        content += '<p>%s</p>' % author.name
    return content
```

Here in the endpoints file i should get the reference of database schema please help me in getting this structure

Point me to some understandable sample or video which can help me to do,I am new to python as well as flask please point some sample and help to learn more thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A basic structure could look like this:

```
/yourapp  
    /run.py  
    /config.py  
    /yourapp  
        /__init__.py
        /views.py  
        /models.py  
        /static/  
            /main.css
        /templates/  
            /base.html  
    /requirements.txt  
    /venv
```

Applied to your example it would look like this.

**run.py**: Start your application.

```
from yourapp import create_app

app = create_app()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**config.py**: Contains configuration, you could add subclasses to differentiate between Development config, Test config and Production config

```
class Config:
    DEBUG = True
    MONGOALCHEMY_DATABASE = 'library'
```

**yourapp/_*init*_.py**: Initialization of your application creating a Flask instance. (Also makes your app a package).

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy
from config import Config

db = MongoAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    
    from views import author_bp
    app.register_blueprint(author_bp)

    return app
```

**yourapp/models.py**: Contains your different models.

```
from . import db

class Author(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()


class Book(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField()
    author = db.DocumentField(Author)
    year = db.IntField();
```

**yourapp/views.py**: Also called the routes.py sometimes. contains your url endpoints and the associated behavior.

```
from flask import Blueprint
from .models import Author

author_bp = Blueprint('author', __name__)

@author_bp.route('/author/new')
def new_author():
    """Creates a new author by a giving name (via GET parameter)
    e.g.: GET /author/new?name=Francisco creates a author named Francisco
    """
    author = Author(name=request.args.get('name', ''))
    author.save()
    return 'Saved :)'

@author_bp.route('/authors/')
def list_authors():
   """List all authors.     
   e.g.: GET /authors"""
   authors = Author.query.all()
   content = '<p>Authors:</p>'
   for author in authors:
       content += '<p>%s</p>' % author.name
   return content
```

**yourapp/static/...** Contains your static files.

**yourapp/templates/..** Contains your templates.

**requirements.txt** has a snapshot of your package dependencies.

**venv** (Virtualenv) folder where your python libs are to be able to work in a contained environment.

References:

[Have a look at this related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415500/common-folder-file-structure-in-flask-app)

[Good example of a widely used project structure.](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask)

Comment: @Beat
 
I have updated my answer to include a more extensive overview of what the structure could look like. Please review again.

Comment: i am following the same directory as above but when i run the run.py i am getting the error has Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flaskApp import create_app
  File "D:\angular-python\pythonAppStructure\flaskApp\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from config import config
ImportError: cannot import name config
 please what i ma doing wrong

Comment: @dhana lakshmi  Try changing it too "from config import Config" (second config with capital letter)

Comment: Thanks, yes i tried it i understood that it from filename import class name but still i am getting the same error can u please create a git repo for above directory structure that would help me a lot please

Comment: I am getting the error has Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "D:\angular-python\pythonAppStructure\flaskApp\__init__.py", line 8, in create_app
    app.config.from_object(config)
NameError: global name 'config' is not defined

Comment: Also change the c to capital C => create_app app.config.from_object(**C**onfig)

Comment: where is this order_bp of app.register_blueprint means by any chance it must be author_bp as defined in views.py because i am getting the below error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "D:\angular-python\pythonAppStructure\flaskApp\__init__.py", line 12, in create_app
    app.register_blueprint(author_bp)
NameError: global name 'author_bp' is not defined

Comment: @dhana-lakshmi You're correct this should be as follows: (I have corrected the response too)
    from views import author_bp
    app.register_blueprint(author_bp)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131148/discussion-between-dhana-lakshmi-and-stijn-diependaele).

Comment: Please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280074/acessing-sub-package-inside-a-package-in-python-flask-is-not-working