# Relative import of a apackage in python flask application

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, package, endpoint

Trying to make the sample flask application more modular,I am new to python and flask trying to  build a sample application  where , I have planned to maintain the folder structure of the application as shown below[image]

where the description of the package  are as fallows

config ---> database configuration details 
flaskApp
1 model--->which has the mongodb schema
2 viewController----> the endpoint to be accessed

static--->
which contains the single html page which i just need to serve (not render it)

The code repo for the same is in github
https://github.com/dhanalakshmiZendynamix/python-Flask-relative-module.git

I am facing following problems
1: I am not finding a easy way to access  the packages to another packages as in folder structure(ie, models inside viewController where the end points are present)

2:Not sure how to serve the html page inside static folder

Tried reading many source 
https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/preface.html
http://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2014/writing-restful-web-services-with-flask.html

But still not sure how to get it working

Please help to adopt to the above folder structure and access to the end point really not sure how to go about it

Any suggestion and pointer would help a lot Thank you

Comment: Check the registered url endpoints in your app.
Start Python on the commandline in your project directory and execute the following commands:
>>> import app
>>> app = app.create_app()
>>> app.url_map

Please add the output to your question.

Comment: my understanding is i am not able to get the reference of db properly please check where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

@dhana lakshmi 
Check the registered url endpoints in your app. 
Start Python on the commandline in your project directory and execute the following commands:

```
>>> import flaskApp 
>>> app = flaskApp.create_app() 
>>> app.url_map
```

Please add the output to your question

And I really think you need to read up a bit on python and flask first, here is a list with some great resources on flask https://github.com/humiaozuzu/awesome-flask

Comment: reposted the question please check