# "Template not found" error even though I have a templates folder using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, templates, error-handling

I'm new to coding and not sure what will help solve the problem, so will post almost all my code

I have

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask

app=Flask(__name__)

views = Blueprint('views', __name__) # importing this

@views.route('/') # whenever the web is loaded with '/'
def home() : # this function will run
    return render_template('base.html')
```

as the views.py

I have

```
from flask import Flask 

def create_app() :
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'eung'

    from .views import views #import line 3 from views.py
    from .auth import auth #import line 3 from auth.py

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/') #every route call from views.py will need to have a prefix of /
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/') #every route call from auth.py will need to have a prefix of /
    return app
```

as the init.py

and

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

as the main.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyKFK.png) this is the image of my directories

1. I tried to import os then make an absolute path but did not do anything
2. I tried adding templates/ into the

```
@views.route('/') # whenever the web is loaded with '/'
def home() : # this function will run
    return render_template('home.html')
```

which did not work

3.  I have tried moving around directories, tried putting main.py in and out of folders, I have tried making base.html a simple line of code but it wasn't the problem with the html file.

4. I have tried more things but it was some time ago and I do not exactly remember.

Comment: try [this folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55862235/6651840)

Comment: also try [this if the above doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37778716/6651840)

Comment: thank you for the folder structures, and I noticed that all of my files are in a virtual environment, while in the posts the virtual environment is elsewhere. would the reason as to why it is not running relate to that too?

Comment: What do you mean about a virtual environment? A _python_ virtual environment or something else?

Comment: `app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')` AND `app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')` is broken. You can't have the same URL prefix for two different blueprints

Comment: There's actually more than just that that's broken. You're creating an app in the blueprint itself and then you also have an app factory function somewhere else to create the app. Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: I looked into your comments and tried interpreting them. I did a python3 -m venv, I made the app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/views') so that they did not clash, and yes I am following a tutorial. I am not entirely sure what you mean by app factory function and all, but I do get that what I'm doing is wrong.

Comment: [This](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/appfactories/#basic-factories) is the app factory. You should only create your app there. Don't create an app in `views.py`. i.e. get rid of `app=Flask(__name__)`

Comment: I am just trying to make a simple website to test what I made for the Google Teachable Machine (simple deep learning program online) and a simple interface to navigate through. I am sure I followed the exact same from the tutorial but cannot seem to find out why my version is not working.